# React Shopping Cart Issue

Tags: reactjs

[image]

As you can see from the image, I can get the number of main menus from (+/-) buttons and calculate the total price and store the main menu information in the localStorage.
But, when I want to add additional feature like extra items with selectbox input type.I can't combine them with the main menu informations(like totalprice,extraItem,extraName,extraPrice etc...)
Here's my input and handleChange function for extra item functionality.

```
<Input
        name={byProduct.extraName}
        value={values[index]}
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(index, e.target.name,e.target.value)}
        style={{ borderRadius: "5px" }}
        type="select"
        id="exampleSelect"
    >
       <option selected="selected">Select</option>
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
    </Input>


  const handleChange = (index,name, value) => {
    let curValues = [...values];
    curValues[index] = value;
    let curName = [...extraName]
    curName[index] = name;
    setValues(curValues);
    setExtraName(curName);
  };

  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
  const [extraName,setExtraName] = useState([]);



  const [extraState, setExtraState] = useState([
    { name: '', count: '' },
  ]);
```

Here's my functions and reducers and other logic for the main menu functionality(it is currently working properly now)

```
function cartReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "add":
      return [...state, action.name];
    case "remove":
      const update = [...state];
      update.splice(update.indexOf(action.name), 1);
      return update;
    default:
      return state;
  }
} 

function totalReducer(state, action) {
  if (action.type === "add") {
    return state + action.price;
  }
  return state - action.price;
}


    function MenuItemModal(props) {
      const [cart, setCart] = useReducer(cartReducer, []);
      const [total, setTotal] = useReducer(totalReducer, 0);
    
      ....
    
     function add(product) {
        const { name, price } = product;
        setCart({ name, type: "add" });
        setTotal({ price, type: "add" });
      }


 const handleLocal = (name, desciption, week) => {
    const myCart = [cart.length, total, name, desciption, week];

    localStorage.setItem("myCart", JSON.stringify(myCart));
    window.location.reload(true);
  };
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by using the Total Reducer for the main menu and making it an extra totalReducer (by-products of the main menu).

But I am sure there is no effective solution.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your values state starts empty if you wanna do like values[index]=something there must be a value at the desired index. Make sure you have some value in there.